# Given a polynomial $P$ and matrix $A$, find matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}P_{(A)}Q=P_{(D)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A: \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 6  \\  
3 & 0    \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$P_{(x)}=x^2+x+2$$
$$P_{(A)}=\begin{pmatrix} 
22 & 12   \\  
6 & 20    \\  
\end{pmatrix}$$
I found the cp of $P_{(A)}$: $$f_{(\lambda)}=(\lambda - 21+\sqrt{73})(\lambda - 21-\sqrt{73})$$
I need to find a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}P_{(A)}Q=P_{(D)}$ when $Q$ is not $[v_1,v_2]$ when $v_1,v_2$ are the eigenvectors for    $P_{(A) } $

Comment: If $Q^{-1}AQ=D$  then $Q^{-1}P_{(A)}Q = P_{(D)}$.

Comment: Can you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $ Q^{-1} A Q = D$, then $Q^{-1} A^n Q = D^n $ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Just sub in the assumption $n$ times to show this fact. Use this with the distributive property of multiplication to prove the result Catalin Zara quoted.

Hint2: 
$$P_{(A)} = A^2 + A +2I $$
so...
$$ Q^{-1} P_{(A)} Q =Q^{-1}( A^2 + A +2I) Q =Q^{-1} A^2 Q + Q^{-1} A Q +2Q^{-1} I Q  $$

Comment: But we're talking about a polynomial, how does this help?

Comment: I've added another hint.